# Reading Multiple Entry from CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, import

I have a CSV file that contains multiple vendors (Cisco, Redhat, vmware..etc), I need a PowerShell script to read this column (vendor) and add separate column "Multiple1 or Multiple2" (Remark) if the CSV contains multiple entries of same vendors.

I have attached screen shot of the sample file.

I tried from end to get this done, but it didn't work.

[image: Sample File]

Comment: For help with your code: *show* your code. Explain what you expected the code to do and what it actually does. "Didn't work" is not a valid problem description.

Comment: The screenshot is the input, or it's the expected result?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, the Screenshot is the expected result, Column A is the input

Comment: Very unclear.. I see 3 Cisco _whatever_ entries in the first column and a value of `Multiple3` behind it. However, Redhat _whatever_ is also there 3 times, but has `Multiple2`. `Microsoft` gets a `Multiple1` but I can see 2 entries there.

Comment: @Theo Sorry, If there is any multiple entry in column "A", we need to add "Multiple" in column "B". I have added Multiple1, Multiple2 to differentiate the vendor names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after Spikeys last comment I had a go at guessing what he might want to achieve.

I created a CSV file:

```
Product,Template
Microsoft Windows,
RedHat Enterprise,
Apple Safari,
Microsoft Windows,
RedHat Enterprise,
RedHat Enterprise,
```

and then wrote the following script. It's commented and produces the following output:

```
Product           Template 
-------           -------- 
Microsoft Windows Multiple2
RedHat Enterprise Multiple3
Apple Safari      Multiple1
Microsoft Windows Multiple2
RedHat Enterprise Multiple3
RedHat Enterprise Multiple3
```

Code:

```
$Csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Book1.csv"

#Hastables have key - value pairs. Example "Microsoft Windows" = 1. Here 'Microsoft Windows' is the key and '1' is the value
[hashtable]$ProductCount = @{}

#Go through each line in the CSV. This returns the product name e.g. Microsoft Windows
ForEach ($Product in $Csv.Product)
{

    #If there us no key for the current product in hashtable $Productcount, then add it with value 1
    If ($ProductCount.Keys -notcontains $Product)
    {
        $ProductCount.Add($Product, 1)
    }
    #If the above does not apply, then increase the value (effectively the count) by 1
    Else
    {
        $ProductCount[$Product] = $ProductCount[$Product] + 1
    }
}



#Go through each row in the CSV file. Each row is returned as it's own object with a 'Product' and 'Template' property
ForEach ($Row in $Csv)
{
    #Extract the count for the current product from hastable $ProductCount
    $Count = $ProductCount[$Row.Product]

    #Set the 'Template' property for the current row object to multipile + the count we got earlier
    $Row.Template = "Multiple$Count"
}

#Save the changes to the CSV file as a new CSV. You can also overwrite your old one if you like
$Csv | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Book2.csv"
```

---

---

---

I don't quite understand your question, but here are some techniques I find useful when working with CSV files.

Example CSV:

```
Name,City
Bob,BlackPool
Alice,Dover
Carl,Manchester
```

Presume you assign the CSV file to a variable like so

```
$CSV = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Stuff.csv"
```

**1.** You can access all rows in a column by typing the variable dot(.) column header, so

```
$CSV.Name
```

returns:

```
Bob
Alice
Carl
```

**2.** To access a row in a CSV file you need to use indexing, so

```
$CSV[1]
```

returns:

```
Name      City
----      ----
Alice     Dover
```

**3.** An easy way to replace a property of a specific row is to filter it using Where-Object. Say I want to change Carl's city to London.

```
$($CSV | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Carl"}).City = "London"
```

Here is what happens:

What's in the parentheses is processed first, so we are selecting a row where the Name property is like "Carl" (You can use wilcard here, so "Ca*" would have worked too). Then, outside of the parentheses, we are setting the city property to "London".

Note: $_ represents the data currently in a pipeline, in this case that's the row containing Carl.

There is more stuff to know, but this might help you the most.

Don't forget to save your changes by using the Export-CSV cmdlet!

```
$CSV | Export-CSV -Path "C:\new.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try to use your suggestions. And I am sorry, that you guys didn't understand my question. the Question is : If we have any multiple entries (Vendor names) in column "A" we need to add Multiple in Column "B"

Comment: Hi Spikey,
Have a look at my edited answer and tell me if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, MondQ : Thank you, the script works as expected. I am able to get the output. :)